# Error with app icon iPhone - iTunes + Cordova + xCode

Tags: iphone, xcode, cordova, app-store-connect

I'm with a problem which don't know like resolve. I already did everything that others users says...
This is the message that is appearing to me:

Missing required icon file - The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '120x120' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 7.0.

Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key "CFBundleIcons": AppIcon29x29

But, in my Resources/ Images.xcassets that is Ok.. Any help on this subject?